# Lambda layers exceeding the size limit - 250 MB unzipped

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

Im stuck in an issue when creating a Lambda layers for multiple lambdas. All these lambdas needs the libraries such as

```
gensim==4.1.2
numpy==1.22.1
pandas==1.4.0
scipy==1.7.3
```

For using ECS - Docker container which has limit upto `10 GB`, Im not sure how to create a sharable docker images, which has these libraries that can be shared across all other lambdas.

I was going through this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20include%20up%20to%20five%20layers%20per%20function%2C%20which%20count%20towards%20the%20unzipped%20deployment%20package%20size%20limit%20of%20250%20MB.%20Layers%20are%20automatically%20set%20as%20private%2C%20but%20they%20can%20be%20shared%20with%20other%20AWS%20accounts%2C%20or%20shared%20publicly.) But not very clear how can I share these libs across the multiple lambdas.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It is entirely unclear what your statement about ECS has to do with Lambda layers. The two things are not related in any way. In any case, I suggest you use the official AWS Data-Wrangler Lambda layer https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/2.15.0/layers.html which comes with most, if not all of those libraries you listed.

Comment: @MarkB My take away is that he is trying to run a lambda function but it is taking to many packages which exceeds the 250mb. Where creating a docker image and pushing it to ECR and then linking it to a lambda function is a good solution.

Comment: @davidbackx Lambda Layers, and Lambda container images are two different things. Also ECR and ECS are two different things. As it is, the question is too confusing to answer.

Comment: @MarkB Yes I know but using ECR is a good solution to fix the 250mb constraint on lambda layers.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered the same problem you are having right now. Firstly you have to create a Dockerfile like the following.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

COPY requirements.txt  ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/.
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Keep in mind this Dockerfile might need some changes to it.

Secondly you will have to push it to ECR

you can use this page as a good example. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-and-push-docker-images-to-aws-ecr/
So if all goes well you now have your docker image on ECR, now you will have too link it to your lambda function. When creating a lambda function you can choose for container if I'm not wrong and this will let you choose one of your images on ECR. now I don't know if this image will interact in any way with other sources on AWS but if this is the case make sure to link IAM policies to your lambda function.
Hope this fixes your problem if not please leave a comment and I'll try to help as much as possible